# Assign each epoch into vars in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently getting an array of times in the arrivaltimes variable:

```
arrivalarray = []
for t in newdata['mode'][0]['route'][0]['direction'][0]['trip']:
    arrivalarray.append(t['sch_arr_dt'])

arrival1, arrival2 = map(int, arrivalarray.split())
```

My error message is:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

When I print arrivalarray, I get this:

> [u'1490498760', u'1490499180', u'1490499600', u'1490500020',
>   u'1490500380', u'1490500800', u'1490501160', u'1490501640',
>   u'1490501940']

Comment: Do you mean you want to *assign* each of these values to a different variable?

Comment: Yes, it's currently printing what the array is giving back. I'd like to assign them into two variables

Comment: your core problem is that you cannot run a split of the times, which is a list: ["123456789", "123456790", "123456791", etc...].  If you need or want to split items in the list, you must specify a particular slice and it must be a string (since split is a string method), i.e. `arrivalarray[0].split()`...

Comment: Am I mistaken by putting them into an array just to split them? @SurestTexas

Comment: They are '_already_' split in the array.. therefore they do not need split... unless the items in the array contain something you want to split further.. like if each item was "1234.5678" and you want to split the parts before and after the '.'  Since the array is already a list (and not string text), you cannot perform a "split()"

Comment: The error you are getting is telling you that you are attempting to `split` a list.. but `split` is not a valid operation (in the error message -'attribute') for a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string, converting the results to integers, and unpacking into two separate variables:

```
arrival1, arrival2 = map(int, arrivaltimes.split())
```

The first step, `arrivaltimes.split()` gives you a list of two strings, `` ['1490493960', '1490494620`] ``.

The second step of mapping the *int()* function turns the list of two strings into list of plain integers, `[1490493960, 1490494620]`.

The last step "unpacks" the list of length two into two separate variables.

Note, in Python 3, the *map()* in the second step returns an iterable of ints rather than a list of ints, but that doesn't change the overall outcome after unpacking.

How this helps get you back in business :-)

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: @beaconhill If that is the case, the your data is something other than want you posted.  Try to use my answer as a basis for experimenting and moving forward.

Comment: @beaconhill Then just take out the ``.split()``.  Please put a little effort into this to help yourself.  We can't write your code for you without seeing the actual data.  We can tell you about ``str.split()`` to parse a string into a list, about ``map(int, seq)`` to convert a list of unicode text into integers, and how to unpack into separate arguments.  At some point though, you're going to have to try it out and put the pieces together.  Programming is a business that rewards thinking about a problem and trying little experiments.  It doesn't reward having someone else doing it for your.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
arrivalarray = []

for t in newdata['mode'][0]['route'][0]['direction'][0]['trip']:
    arrivalarray.append(t['sch_dep_dt'])

arrival1 = arrivalarray[0]
arrival2 = arrivalarray[1]
```